# SQL SUM of a ntext field using LEN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum, content-length

I want to count the number of characters in a `ntext` column and then get the `SUM` For example I have the following query:

```
SELECT LEN(field1) AS Length, field1 
FROM table
```

It will return results like:

```
|Length|field1|
-------------------
  4     abcd
  6     abcdef
  4     abcd
```

I now want to get the `SUM` of the Length field. Using MS SQL 2008.

Comment: so do you want to get a total of `14`? right? see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpliest solution would be, (*without using a subquery or any other that could decrease the performance*)

```
SELECT SUM(LEN(field1)) AS totalLength
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was simple!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Since you are using sql server 2008 , you could use common table expression(CTE):

```
;with cte as(
     SELECT LEN(field1) AS Length, field1 
     FROM table)
select sum(Length) as sumOfLenght from CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find Length and then sum of that length...

```
SELECT SUM(LEN(field1)) FROM table
```